# Applying a function with several arguments and return values from column data to new columns

Tags: python-3.x

bRelatively new to Python and can't seem to find a worked example for my problem.

I've written a function with 7 arguments and 6 return values. (The function works fine when you define the arguments as static numbers).

However I need the 7 arguments to grab the data from 7 different columns in a dataframe that I have constructed (df).

I then want to create 6 new columns for each of the 6 greek letter return values in the same df.

So far I have tried the following with no luck:

```
df[['value', 'delta', 'gamma', 'theta', 'vega', 'rho']] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x['option_type'],x['forward price'],x['T'], x['off_peak'], x['Discount'], x['Discount_1'], x['off_peak_delta']), axis=1)
df
```

My function looks like the following (shortened for simplicity):

```
def my_function(option_type, fs, x, t, r, b, v):

    if option_type == "a":
        value = fs * math.exp((b - r) * t)
        delta = math.exp(b - r)
        gamma = math.exp((b - r) * fs)
        theta = -(fs * v)
        vega = fs * t__sqrt
        rho = x * t 
    else
        other_code

    return value, delta, gamma, theta, vega, rho
```

I think this should be a straight forward solution but can't seem to get a breakthrough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your my_function is not returning the right "form" of a series. There may be a more elegant formulation but the following works:

```
def my_function(x1,x2,x3,x4, x5, x6, x7):
    return pd.DataFrame({'value':[x2*math.exp(x6-x5)*x4], 
                         'delta': [math.exp(x6-x5)], 
                         etc...}).loc[0]
```

Then, your existing lambda function will work. Note that the values of the dataframe-building dict are single-element functions, so you're essentially making a dataframe and taking the first row. The same could be achieved with the right pd.Series function.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! FYI, If you'd like to accept my answer, you can find a star button under the up and down vote arrows to do that.